# How to add a row for "TOTAL" after each date and get the total of amount in that total row in google sheets?

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I want to add a row after similar dates summing up that day's total.

My dates get sorted automatically after each new edit.

[image]

Comment: Please, post your picture here, as a text table. Also, what have you tried?

Answer (score 2):

If you want to see the daily total, you could use a pivot table further along your sheet (or another sheet). Alternatively, you could use `query` function like this:

`=query(A:H,"select A,count(A),sum(F) where A is not null group by A label count(A) 'Cheques paid in', sum(F) 'Daily amount' ",1)`

The example could go in cell `J1` on your sheet. There is no need to sort your dates since the `group by` does that.